# Spoofed iMessage? Apple account breach? What are the possible ways this happened?

Tags: spoofing, apple

See the screenshot below. A friend asked me about this. Person #1 had a group text thread with Person #2 and Person #3. At the top, Person #2 sent a photo and a message. Person #3 replied. Then there appears a rude reply from Person #1 just a minute later. That reply was not sent by Person #1. Person #1 does not see that message that supposedly came from her. This screenshot is from Person #2's phone.

You can see that someone (Person #2) made an in-line reply to that message, and it was given a thumbs-down. The outgoing messages are blue also. So I believe this shows for sure all messages here are iMessages.

iMessage is a secure system with end-to-end encryption. So my thoughts are that the only way this could happen were if Person #1's Apple login were breached by someone else. I know SMS/MMS spoofs happen frequently and that system is an insecure dinosaur. But do spoofs happen in the iMessage system?

Another possibility is someone close used her phone for a minute. The message does not show on her phone. However it could have been deleted after it was sent. I know you can delete individual messages like that.

Any other possibilities?

[image]

Comment: My first thought is that this is a social attack rather than a technical one. Does person #1 have a housemate with a bad sense of humor? Maybe their phone doesn't require a pw to reply. Or maybe they have iMessage on their desktop and that wasn't locked.

Comment: @AdamKatz Thanks, good point. I think she has only a Windows computer, not Mac, but I will check.